# Search in Qml ListView contact model

Tags: filter, contacts, qml

What I have is a listview, to show list of contacts. Also, there is a search box and a label. Based on the text typed in the search box, the contact list will be filtered.

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.nokia.symbian 1.1
import com.nokia.extras 1.1
import QtMobility.contacts 1.1

Window {
id: window

StatusBar {
    id: statusBar
    anchors.top: window.top
    Text {
        id: statusBarTitle
        text: "Contacts"
        color: "#ffffff"
    }
}

ContactModel {
    id: contactModel

    filter:
        IntersectionFilter {
        DetailFilter {
        detail: ContactDetail.PhoneNumber
        field: PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber
        value: PhoneNumber.Mobile
        }

        UnionFilter {
            DetailFilter {
            detail: ContactDetail.Name
            field: Name.FirstName
            value: searchbox.searchText
            matchFlags: Filter.MatchStartsWith
            }

            DetailFilter {
            detail: ContactDetail.Name
            field: Name.LastName
            value: searchbox.searchText
            matchFlags: Filter.MatchStartsWith
            }

            DetailFilter {
            detail: ContactDetail.DisplayLabel
            field: DisplayLabel.Label
            value: searchbox.searchText
            matchFlags: Filter.MatchStartsWith
            }
        }
    }

    sortOrders:
        SortOrder {
        detail: ContactDetail.Name
        field: Name.FirstName
        direction: Qt.AscendingOrder
    }
}

Component {
    id: contactListDelegate
    ListItem {
        id: listItem

        Image {
            id: avatar
            source: contact.thumbnail
            sourceSize.width: 60
            sourceSize.height: 60
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.left: parent.left
        }

        ListItemText {
            id: nameText
            text: contact.name.firstName + " " + contact.name.lastName
            color: "white"
            anchors.left: avatar.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            font.family: "Helvetica"
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
    }
}

ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.top: searchbox.bottom
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.bottom: toolBar.top
    clip: true
    model: contactModel
    delegate: contactListDelegate
    visible: true
}

SearchBox {
    id: searchbox
    anchors.top: statusBar.bottom
    placeHolderText: "Search Contact"

    onSearchTextChanged: {
        searchingBusyIndicator.running = true
        searchingBusyIndicator.visible = true
        searchTimeoutTimer.restart()
    }
}

Label {
    id: noMatchesLabel
    anchors.centerIn: listView
    visible: false
    text: "No matches"
}

BusyIndicator{
    id: searchingBusyIndicator
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    platformInverted: window.platformInverted
    width: 80
    height: 80
    visible: false
}

Timer{
    id: searchTimeoutTimer
    interval: 1000

    onTriggered: {
        searchingBusyIndicator.running = false
        searchingBusyIndicator.visible = false
    }
}

ToolBar {
    id: toolBar
    anchors.bottom: window.bottom
    tools: ToolBarLayout {
        id: toolBarLayout
        ToolButton {
            flat: true
            iconSource: "toolbar-back"
            onClicked: {
                Qt.quit()
            }
        }
        ToolButton {
            flat: true
            iconSource: "toolbar-search"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now I need to change the visible property of the list view to false & the label property to true, when there is no matches in the list. How to achieve that.?

What's happening now is, the application crashes and terminates when there is no matches.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days while find solution of this problem...

here is my fix:

```
ContactModel {
     ...........
     onRowsInserted: {
     if(last === 0)
     {
         noMatchesLabel.visible = true;
         listView.model = {};
     }
     else
     {
         noMatchesLabel.visible = false;
         listView.model = contactModel;
     }
}
```

While the contactModel haven't contacts because of using filters, we swap the model of listView to empty one. In that way the app doesn't crash